# Flutter the named parameter 'border' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i'm trying to create a border for a button, but I get this error:
"The named parameter 'border' isn't defined"
I know that the widgets are updated, but I can't find why the parameter is not identified.

The code is here:

````
  const ChooseOptionScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.4,
              child: OutlinedButton(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
                },
                child: const Text('Login'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.4,
              child: OutlinedButton(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
                },
                child: const Text('Register'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you look-up the description of OutlinedButton, you will not find any parameter called `border`. Instead you need to use `style: ButtonStyle()´. For example:

```dart
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
```

Comment: Oh. I completely missed that. Thank you very much! :)